# Why are there many php.ini files in a system?

Tags: php, apache, configuration-files

I just want to know why both Apache httpd and php environment need a php.ini file. Does modifying one of them require updating the other?

If someone can recommend a specific book, article or tutorial to help me understand this, that would be helpful thank you.

Comment: Where are many `php.ini` files?

Comment: One for the CLI, one for the web server. So, the answer is generally no: they are updated independently, as they are for different things. Your CLI processes generally require more memory, whereas web processes need to be small and lightweight. Command line stuff and web pages tend to need different modules, too.

Comment: You can have a php.ini or even a http.conf for each vhost, so a server can be setup to server multiple clients with different configurations

Comment: try running this code.. <?php phpinfo(); ?>
ull get a lot of information as to what files and settings the server is referring to, including paths to the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) exists for the global web server process. It can also exist for each [individual](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-specify-different-phpini-files-each-websites-apache) `vhost`.

It is searched for in the following order:

- The `PHPIniDir` directive defined by the vhost
- The `PHPRC` environment variable (as of PHP 5.2.0)
- If on Windows and PHP 5.2.0 or greater, the following registry keys
  `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z]`, `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y]` and `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x]`, where x, y and z mean the PHP major, minor and release versions. If there is a value for IniFilePath in any of these keys, the first one found will be used as the location of the php.ini (Windows only).
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP], value of IniFilePath (Windows only).
- The current working directory
- The web server's directory
- If on Windows, the Windows directory (`C:\Windows`)